# PowerShell function return boolean doesn't work

Tags: function, powershell

Good day,

in our Active Directory we have two groups for user sync for a third party system.
First group contains all users for that system. Second group contains all members from first group that are disabled or expired. This is necessary for licensing.

Now I want to automate that procedure with a PowerShell script.

```
$d3_UserGrp = Get-ADGroup -Identity "d3_users"
$d3_DisabledUserGrp = Get-ADGroup -Identity "d3_Users disabled v2"

Function IsUserActive 
{
    param(
        $AD_User
    )

    #$return = $false
    
    $AD_User.SamAccountName
    $AD_User.AccountExpirationDate

    $now = get-date

    if ( $AD_User.AccountExpirationDate -ne $null ) {
        #"Account has expiration date"
        if ( $AD_User.AccountExpirationDate -lt $now ) {
            "Account expired"
        } else {
            #Write-Host "account not expired"
        }
    } elseif ( $AD_User.Enabled -ne $true ) {
        "Account not active"
    } else {
        #"everything fine with that account"
        #return $true
    }
    
    #write-host "return is $return"


    #return $false
}



$grp = Get-ADGroupMember $d3_UserGrp

foreach ( $username in $grp ) 
{
    
    $ad_user = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties AccountExpirationDate, DisplayName


    if ( IsUserActive -AD_User $ad_user )
    {
        write-host "add $ad_user.SamAccountName"
        #Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $d3_DisabledUserGrp -Members $ad_user -Confirm:$false
    } 
    else 
    {
        write-host "remove $ad_user.SamAccountName"
        #Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $d3_DisabledUserGrp -Members $ad_user -Confirm:$false
    }
    ""
}
```

This won't work. The script always add's the ad users in the second group.

Any idea why?

Best regards

Comment: Just to point out the obvious that in your example all return statements are commented out and therefore won't work :). I hope that isn't the issue, if not how are you calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function outputs multiple values. For example, it's always returning:

```
$AD_User.SamAccountName
$AD_User.AccountExpirationDate
```

That means `IsUserActive -AD_User $ad_user` is always going to evaluate to true.

Consider:

```
$test = @(1, $null, $false)

if ($test) { 'It is true' } else { 'It is false' }
```

Even when the multiple values should all be false individually, it will not be false:

```
$test = @($null, $false)

if ($test) { 'It is true' } else { 'It is false' }
```

You need to make sure that the output of your function is *only* the return value. You can do this by making sure that you use `Write-Host` when you want to write to the screen and not return output.

Try:

```
Function IsUserActive 
{
    param(
        $AD_User
    )

    #$return = $false
    
    Write-Host $AD_User.SamAccountName
    Write-Host $AD_User.AccountExpirationDate

    $now = get-date

    if ( $null -eq $AD_User.AccountExpirationDate ) {
        Write-Host "Account has expiration date"
        if ( $AD_User.AccountExpirationDate -lt $now ) {
            Write-Host "Account expired"
            $false
        } else {
            Write-Host "account not expired"
            $true
        }
    } elseif ( $AD_User.Enabled -ne $true ) {
        Write-Host "Account not active"
        $false
    } else {
        Write-Host "everything fine with that account"
        $true
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, that solved my problem.
I wonder if this works in different way as in other script languages. There I have to give an explicit return value.

Never the less: thanks again!